# Required android.support.v4.app.Fragment, it already exist

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

my imports already includes android.support.v4.app.Fragment but still it shows me this error "Found : hind.jai.com.jaihind.PageFragment required android.support.v4.app.Fragment". I'm following this tutorial [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout)

SampleFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
package hind.jai.com.jaihind;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Rishik on 19-04-2015.
 */
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1); //error in PageFragment
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to make sure PageFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: If I extend public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter to android.support.v4.app.Fragment, it again throws an error for .Fragment

Comment: I mean you need to make sure that the PageFragment class that you call in PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1) extends Fragment. Can you post the code of PageFragment?

Comment: Hey mate, sorry for late reply, wasn't around to check my question, I just changed my guide, but again I'm facing the same error, as like before.

EDIT: This is the tutorial that I'm following now 
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

And I'm facing an error in ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: @CarbonAssassin Nice one mate